# Check null values in multiple data frames in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

```
df_list=['df1','df2','df3']
for i in df_list:
    null_status=i.isnull().values.any()
    if null_status is True:
        print(i + "has null values")
    else:
        print(i + "doesn't have null values")
```

Error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'isnull'
```

I've tried multiple ways but cannot get df in iteration.

Comment: `df_list` is `list`, you're iterating over list.

Comment: you have a list of strings, probably representing the name of the variables for your dataframes, so if you want to check in the dataframes themself, the list should be `df_list=[df1,df2,df3]`, no `''`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Ben.T suggested, your list should have the dataframe objects rather than their names. However, in this way you will not be able to print the dataframe names in the `if-else` statement.

So you can do a workaround like this (if you don't have dozens of dataframes): create a list of dataframe objects and a list of dataframe names, and iterate over them in parallel.

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
df_list_names = ["df1", "df2", "df3"]

for i, n in zip(df_list, df_list_names):
    null_status = i.isnull().values.any()
    if null_status:
        print(n + " has null values")
    else:
        print(n + " doesn't have null values")
```

Example output

```
# df1 has null values
# df2 doesn't have null values
# df3 doesn't have null values
```